# Why I see '0' when I use current_user.has_role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, roles, cancan

In view I set validation for roles (gems cancan and rolify).

As example in HAML

```
=if current_user.has_role? :admin
  = link_to current_user.name, '#'
```

Generated HTML

```
<a href="#">Administrator</a>
"
0




"
```

Why I see '0'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `-` in front of your if statement, probably:

```
- if current_user.has_role? :admin
  = link_to current_user.name, '#'
```

When you use an `=` there, it's going to display the result of that expression, which is not what you want.